# Browser compatibility code for all functions, events, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used onmouseover and onmouseout for viewing image but its not working in chrome. need solution for this problem.

script is

```
<script>
var img;

window.onload = function () {
      img = document.getElementById ("img");
   }
</script>

<img style= "position:absolute;TOP:90px; LEFT:185px;visibility:hidden;" 
     class="two" 
     id="img" 
     src="services/web2.png" 
     width="800" height="500" alt=""/>

 <div class="item home">
    <img src="imagess/bg_home.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
    <h2>IT</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="target4" 
              onMouseOver="img.style.visibility='visible'; img.src='services/web2.png'"
              onMouseOut="img.style.visibility='hidden';">Sales & Service</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="target5" 
               onMouseOver="img.style.visibility='visible'; img.src='services/web2.png'" 
               onMouseOut="img.style.visibility='hidden';">CCTV</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="target6" 
                onMouseOver="img.style.visibility='visible'; img.src='services/web2.png'"
                onMouseOut="img.style.visibility='hidden';">DVR</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have tagged your question "jQuery"?

Comment: What does the error console say in Chrome?

Comment: @fork: Yes, that is the reason why I've asked. Has the OP included it but does not use it? Or does he want to use but does not know how?

Comment: @Bergi he just says that onmouseover and onmouseout dont work in Chrome. Nothing else.

Comment: You do not need to camelcase your attribute names, although that isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: @fork: He had tagged his question "jQuery", Suresh Pattu has now [removed it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13321849/revisions)

Comment: The error message is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` ( just stuck this code into a fiddle )

Answer (score 1):

You are using very obtrusive javascript, it is simply bad practice.
So tracing the mistake don't make so much sense.
People who suggested using jQuery are very much right, and you will do yourself a favour
by taking that advice.

Using onMouseOver and other javascript directly on DOM element is just not how things are done anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your JavaScript

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = document.getElementById('img'),
        links = ['target4', 'target5', 'target6'],
        i = links.length, e,
        over = function over(){
            img.style.visibility='visible';
            img.src='services/web2.png';
        },
        out = function out(){
            img.style.visibility='hidden';
        };

    while( --i >= 0 ){
        e = document.getElementById(links[i]);
        e.addEventListener('mouseover', over, false);
        e.addEventListener('mouseout', out, false);
    }
}​
```

from your HTML

```
<img id="img" class="two" src="services/web2.png" alt=""/>

 <div class="item home">
    <img src="imagess/bg_home.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
    <h2>IT</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a id="target4" href="target4">Sales &amp; Service</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a id="target5" href="target5">CCTV</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a id="target6" href="target6">DVR</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
  </div>​
```

Working [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XtR7h/1/).

Answer (score -1):

You better use jQuery for that kind of stuff, that should work on all browsers.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Not necessarily. I have nothing against jQuery, but let's try to find what is wrong with his existing code.

Comment: @Asad i said "You better" which basically means also "Not necessarily".

Comment: @Asad And there is nothing wrong with his code as its working under other browsers. So how do you fix something that works? You cant, you have to rethink it. And thats what i mean with my answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

css:

```
#img {
 position:absolute;
 top:90px;
 left:185px;
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

  var $img = $('#img');

  // selector container for image
  var $container = $('.item');

  $container.find('ul li a')
    .bind('mouseover', function(event) {

        var target = $(this).attr('href'); //if you need to differentiate

        $img
           .css('visibility', 'visible')
           .attr('src', 'services/web2.png');

    })
    .bind('mouseout', function(event) {

        var target = $(this).attr('href'); //if you need to differentiate

        $img
           .css('visibility', 'hidden');

    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<img class="two" id="img" src="services/web2.png" width="800" height="500" alt="" />
<div class="item home">
   <img src="imagess/bg_home.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
   <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
   <h2>IT</h2>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="target4">Sales & Service</a></li>
     <li><a href="target5">CCTV</a></li>
     <li><a href="target6">DVR</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('li a').mouseenter(function () {
                $('li a').hide(1);
            }).mouseout(function () {
                $('li a').show(1);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="link" href="http://www.tivo.com/">DVR</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```